# Why do I see multiple processes with the same name

Tags: 11.10, process

Sometimes when I open the **System Monitor** I see multiple processes with the same name. Some examples are the Plugin-Container,  Gwibber and others. Why do they appear multiple times in System Manager and is there a way to at least visibly unite them together so it shows the same process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to unite them. But a common reason that multiple instances of the same process is listed is because multiple processes are active at that moment. For example, Firefox has a Plugin-Container that is a multi-process design. Google Chrome is a multi-process web-browser. So when Chrome is run you will always see multiple instances of Chrome listed.